# TLS handshake decryption

Tags: encryption, wireshark, keys, tcp-ip, decryption

I have an offline Pcap file with a lot of data from many different protocols. I would like to decrypt the Transmission Control Protocol data from the 3-way handshake.

[image: Transmission Control Protocol details]

Transmission Control Protocol STREAM

[image: Transmission Control Protocol details]

Transmission Control Protocol STREAM

[image: Transmission Control Protocol details]

Transmission Control Protocol STREAM

[image: Transmission Control Protocol Details]